How do I change the spacing around \chapter with titlesec?
I am having trouble with \titlespacing from the titlesec package.  For some reason, I am getting strange errors, even though I think I followed the directions from the documentation.  Here is my Minimal Failing Example:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\itshape\Huge\filleft}{\thechapter.}{\widthof{\quad}}{}[]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{36pt}{60pt}[]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
Test Text.

\end{document}

The code seems to place the correct spacing around everything the chapter heading, but I get the following 2 errors at run-time:
Chapter 1.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.10 \chapter{Test Chapter}
                           
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.10 \chapter{Test Chapter}

The problem is definitely with \titlespacing, since commenting out that line makes the code run perfectly --- sans the spacing changes, of course.

\widthof can only be used in specific situations when setting a length parameter. Off these contexts it's illegal.
However \quad leaves a space of 1em in the current font.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\itshape\Huge\filleft}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{36pt}{60pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

Test Text.

\end{document}



For some reason my code gave me no errors if I just removed the final []s at the end of the format and spacing commands.  And it seemed to run correctly.  HOWEVER, by changing \widthof{\quad} into 1em, I was able to then run the code with and without the final []s.
